# Xdebug breaks on access to class static property

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I've a problem with Xdebug in my development environment.

```
FROM library/php:5.5-apache

RUN apt-get -qqy update && apt-get -qqy install \ 
               libpq-dev \
               libmcrypt-dev \
               libxml2-dev \
               ssl-cert \
               vim \
               git \
               mc \
        && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# compile and add xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=xdebug.so" >> "/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini"

# configure apache and vhosts
RUN a2enmod rewrite ssl \
        && a2ensite 000-default default-ssl

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Xdebug settings:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_host=172.17.42.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Everything works good but one thing. When debugging the code:

```
<?php
class A {
    static private $a;

    static public function init() {
        self::$a = 123;
    }
}

A::init();
```

If I set a breakpoint on `self::$a = 123;` or step into the line, I get:

```
Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: A::$a
```

If I don't step into that line, the debugging session continues without any problems.

What's wrong?

Comment: Same problem with PHP 5.4.43 with Xdebug v2.3.2.
Own build via docker.

Comment: I've used different xdebug versions, different debug clients. I've installed xdebug via pecl and compile by myself. The problem must be somewhere inside official docker php image

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I tested it with PHPStorm9 and Netbeans8. The problem occured in both IDEs.

Comment: I've got the same issue with PHPStorm10, docker image php:56-apache

Comment: I've seen the same with Eclipse and the following PHP-fpm version using nginx:
PHP 5.6.14-0+deb8u1
Zend Engine v2.6.0
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev
    with Xdebug v2.3.2

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/133 and the xdebug bug tracker report: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1185

Answer (score 8):

I think it's a bug somewhere in XDebug - see these bug reports

- http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1185
- https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/133

Meanwhile you may be able to sort of work around the issue by using the `xdebug_break()` function just AFTER the line that's throwing the exception and continue debugging from there. I tried setting a breakpoint on the line after the exception is thrown and I found that a breakpoint wasn't enough to stop it throwing an exception.

Not a perfect solution but hopefully those bugs will get fixed soon.

**Update**: The problem has been nailed down to a combination of a specific version of PHP with a specific version of Xdebug and a specific compiler used for some images. A [potential solution](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/133#issuecomment-304933175) has been proposed in the docker-library bug report, which involves installing specific versions of these packages, if you're using Docker.

```
FROM php:5.6.3-apache

# XDebug
RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && yes | apt-get update \
    && yes | apt-get install php5-xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
        && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
      && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Comment: FYI. This is still a bug in PHP 5.6.40 and Xdebug 2.5.5 (the last PHP 5). Even though the discussion in issue 133 reckons it was fixed in PHP 5.6.30ish, it's not. The only solution I got to work was Derrick's recommended change to the source build (-O0 flag). So I don't think it will ever get fixed now, considering it's not a problem in 7.

Comment: This is definitely better than nothing. And such a pain, because it happens for each use of a static variable. So you have to litter them all over the place. When you say "hopefully those bugs will get fixed soon", it makes me sad because I'm using an old version of PHP on purpose in docker to have parity with what's used in a legacy production app. As in... it will never be fixed. Still, upvoted because it's SOMETHING.

Comment: @TylerCollier I've added some more detail to the answer above as there is a suggested solution which may help.

Comment: @ec2011 Unless I'm misunderstanding, it doesn't seem that specific. I'm using PHP 5.4.45 and Xdebug 2.4.1 on Debian Jessie (docker). But thanks for pointing me to that github issue, as I found one of the solutions worked for me. I wrote my notes about it [here](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/133#issuecomment-711421681).

Comment: Saved me! work around the issue by using the xdebug_break()

Answer (score 2):

The error described can only be reproduced in the official PHP5 images. PHP 7 images work just fine, and when building a custom PHP5 FPM image from jessie or ubuntu, the error also does not occur.