# Accessing a private static member

Tags: php, static-methods, static-members

Not sure if this stopped working due to a recent upgrade to PHP5.6 or what.

```
namespace Data;

class AWS{
    private static $config;

    public static function setup($config){
        if(isset(self::$config)){
            throw new Exception("AWS has already been setup.");
        }
        self::$config = $config;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then from a different file:

```
use \Data\AWS;
AWS::setup($array_of_configs);
```

Calling setup gives:

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property:
>   CoPatient\Data\AWS::$config in /var/www/html/src/data/AWS.php on line
>   24

Using xdebug I can confirm that `$config` contains an 1-d associative array.

**Edit:** This only seems to be happening if I've got an xdebug listener running.

Comment: Unless you have a bunch of header comments and use statements, that doesn't look like *line 24*

Comment: Shared code [should work flawlessly](https://3v4l.org/PhqoK), the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: How do you call setup? If you call it from an object instance, it cannot work. You should call it simply AWS::setup( $config ).

Comment: @Denis, there are some namespacing and (presumably) not-relevant static member initialization lines that I have omitted.  That `self::$config = $config` line is, in fact, line 24.

Comment: @RiccardoC `AWS::setup($aws_conf);`

Comment: I get this feeling this is due to a combination of xdebug and the php:5.6-latest docker box, as seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571101/xdebug-breaks-on-access-to-class-static-property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're just accessing it wrong when calling the method. Probably using an instance selector like: `$a = new AWS(); $a->setup();`

```
class AWS {
    private static $config;

    public static function setup($config){
        if(isset(self::$config)){
            throw new Exception("AWS has already been setup.");
        }
        var_dump(self::$config);
        self::$config = $config;
        var_dump(self::$config);
    }

    public static function getConfig() {
       return self::$config;   
    }
}

AWS::setup(array('test'));
var_dump(AWS::getConfig());
```

Should give an output of:

```
NULL
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
}
```

Fiddle: http://www.tehplayground.com/#idd0F1WGk

Comment: The class is being accessed statically: `AWS::setup($aws_conf);`

Comment: @ParrisVarney I've added a Fiddle to show the correct output. If you're accessing statically and still receiving that error, there must be an issue with code somewhere else that you have not provided.

Comment: It's definitely happening at that point in the code judging by the error message and watching what happens in the step debugger, but I think you're right with saying it's not a code issue with the code I've shared.  So I've marked your answer as accepted.  FWIW I'm 99% certain I'm experiencing the issue described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571101/xdebug-breaks-on-access-to-class-static-property.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ParrisVarney Thank you for following up. I haven't seen/heard of that issue before. Hope it gets resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I think You just don't do $aws = new AWS() before call setup. That's right ?

Comment: The class is being accessed statically: `AWS::setup($aws_conf);`